# Wrongly named variables in mysqld.cnf (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, mysql

Recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and found that the default configuration file for MySQL has a few wrongly named variables, i.e. system variables whose name has changed over versions.

In the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` there are the following lines:

```
table_cache            = 64
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

The current version of MySQL in use requires these to be named:

```
table_open_cache
slow_query_log_file
log_queries_not_using_indexes
```

Respectively. Is this a bug in the Ubuntu release or a problem somewhere else?  My question is:

**Who is to be blamed for this and should a bug report be filed?**

At the very least, perhaps some frustrated individual will find this question and get answers.

Comment: I am not familiar with MySQL but at first make sure that the options are actually wrong with respect to the version installed. I have seen so many programs change directive names from version to version.

Comment: Yes, they are wrong.  The configuration file is installed along with the package and the variable names don't work with the version it accompanies.  If you use them as is it will crash mysqld

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the `mysql-server-5.7` package to test:

```
$ apt-get download 'mysql-server*'
Get:1 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 [10.1 kB]
Get:2 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 [2,584 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 [7,503 kB]
Fetched 10.1 MB in 0s (63.8 MB/s)
$ dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile mysql-server-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb| tar x ./etc/mysql
$ grep -e table_cache -e log_slow_queries -e log-queries-not-using-indexes ./etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
#table_cache            = 64
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

All three lines were commented out. I'm not sure a commented-out line is a big deal. The package maintainer probably ignores them.

Comment: Normally when I encounter commented out lines in a config file, I presume that uncommenting them and/or changing their value will not result in an error and crash the server.  If this is due to negligence on behalf of the package maintainer, I think it's high time they updated the config file to match the version it comes with.

Comment: @billynoah file a bug. :shrug:

Comment: I just did.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1592729.  In retrospect, this questino may in fact be off topic since it's more of a gripe than an actual question.  Just wasn't really clear about who's responsible - but as you pointed out, it's the package maintainer.  Thanks.

Comment: @muru or read the changlog ;)

Comment: Right - but shouldn't the package work out of the box?  I'm of the opinion that users should not be required to read a changelog to know that the names of directives supplied with the version they installed will actually break their server.

Comment: @billynoah I disagree on that - if you go about changing the configuration, you better know what you're doing. That's why I don't consider commented lines to be a big deal - I wouldn't change those without looking them up.

Comment: No, not all ...  but when I see a problem like that it is my 1st place to go ;-)

I would say: file a bug against the config file. That is probably on the Ubuntu end, not mysql.